# Why is Mongoose updating the database immediately when a property is updated and not on save()

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I had a strange issue where I was getting a ParallelSaveError when running `save()` on a document, even though it was the only time that I was saving the data to the database. I did a little more digging and found that Mongoose is automatically updating the database when a property is changed:

Route for updating data:

```
update: function(req, res){
    const updatedUser = userLogic.updateUser(res.locals.user, req.body);
    return;
},
```

userLogic.updateUser() function:

```
updateUser: function(user, data){
    if(!data) throw new SyntaxError("arguments");
    if(!user) throw new TypeError("user");
    email = data.email.toLowerCase();
    if(!isValidEmail(email)) throw new SyntaxError("invalid email");

    user.name = data.name;
    user.email = email;
    user.country = data.country;
    user.address = data.address;
    return;
}
```

When I change the database at this point, it has already been updated. In the route function I was calling `.save()` on the updated user, but it was giving that error. I have never encountered this happening before. Why is Mongoose updating the database without any save?

Comment: Can you provide the code around what you posted? I assume your problem happens at `user.name = data.name`, right? Is something happening if you comment out the assignations? Have you checked the schema? Maybe you trigger something automatically. By what you posted there's no point to save

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully to see if save() comes after the function you call

Comment: `save()` is nowhere in/around/after the function.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose creates and executes an update query directly on the database, bypassing the need to call .save() on each individual document. This can result in faster and more efficient updates, especially when updating multiple documents at once.

As a result, when you call save() on the updated user object in your route function, Mongoose detects that the document has already been updated and tries to update it again, causing the ParallelSaveError. To fix this issue, you can either remove the call to save() in your route function or use the findOneAndUpdate() method provided by Mongoose to update the document in the database. Using findOneAndUpdate() will prevent the ParallelSaveError from occurring because it updates the document in a single atomic operation.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/